# Scikit Learn RandomForest Memory Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to run scikit learn random forest algorithm on the mnist handwritten digits dataset. During the training of the algorithm the system goes into a Memory Error. Please tell me what should I do to fix this issue.

**CPU Statistics:** Intel Core 2 Duo with 4GB RAM

The shape of dataset is **60000, 784**. the complete error as on the linux terminal is as follows:

```
> File "./reducer.py", line 53, in <module>
>     main()   File "./reducer.py", line 38, in main
>     clf = clf.fit(data,labels) #training the algorithm   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py", line 202,
> in fit
>     for i in xrange(n_jobs))   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/parallel.py", line 409, in
> __call__
>     self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/parallel.py", line 295, in
> dispatch
>     job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/parallel.py", line 101, in
> __init__
>     self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py", line 73, in
> _parallel_build_trees
>     sample_mask=sample_mask, X_argsorted=X_argsorted)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 476, in fit
>     X_argsorted=X_argsorted)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 357, in
> _build_tree
>     np.argsort(X.T, axis=1).astype(np.int32).T)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line
> 680, in argsort
>     return argsort(axis, kind, order) MemoryError
```

Comment: what are the parameters you use to create RandomForest?

Comment: i am just using **n_estimators=10**

Comment: try to set `n_jobs=1`

Answer (score 4):

Either set `n_jobs=1` or upgrade to the bleeding edge version of scikit-learn. The problem is that the currently released version uses multiple *processes* to fit trees in parallel, which means that the data (`X` and `y`) need to be copied to these processes. The next release will use threads instead of processes, so the tree learners share memory.

Comment: I did try adding n_jobs=1 but still get the same error. Can you please  provide some way in which I may be able to use the new version of scikit-learn?

Comment: @Piyush If you get this error with `n_jobs=1`, then upgrading won't help. Is `X` in `np.float32` format initially? Is it Fortran-ordered (column-major)?

Answer (score 2):

### Scikit-learn Dev Team improved a lot both memory management & performance on `.ensemble` methods

With all due respect to other opinions, **`scikit-learn 0.16.1`** does not proof itself to have the "*nasty*" **`X`**, **`y`** replicas, cited for some early versions.

Due to some other reasons, I have spent rather a long time on the **`RandomForestRegressor()`** hyperparameter's landscape, incl. their memory footprint problems.

As of `0.16.1`, there was **less than 2%** increase in the parallel-joblib memory requirements above a default `n_jobs = 1` to **`{ 2, 3, ... }`**

Co-father of recent `scikit-learn` releases, @glouppe, posted [a marvelous & insight-full presentation (2014-Aug, rel. 0.15.0)](http://www.slideshare.net/glouppe/accelerating-random-forests-in-scikitlearn), incl. comparisons with R-based and other known RandomForest frameworks.

IMHO, pages 25+ speak about techniques, that increase speed, incl. the **`np.asfortranarray(...)`**, however these seem to me ( without any experimental proof ) as just internal directions shared inside the Scikit-learn development team, rather than a recommendation for us, the mortals, who live in the "outer world".

### Regression or Classification?

Yes, that matters. Some additional Feature-engineering efforts & testing might be in place if not doing a full-scale FeatureSET vector bagging. Your learner seems to be the Classifier case, so go deeper into:

1. experiment on non-default settings for `max_features` et al
2. use O/S services to handle larger virtual memory **`mkswap`** + **`swapon`** if needed after tuning the learner in 1.

### Addendum

After another round of testing, there has appeared one interesting observation.

While a **`.set_params( n_jobs = -1 ).fit( X, y )`** configuration was used successfully on training the `RandomForestRegressor()` the ugly surprise came later, once trying to use **`.predict( X_observed )`** on such pre-trained object.

There a similar *map/reduce*-bound memory issue was reported (with 0.17.0 now).

**Nevertheless**, the same **`.set_params( n_jobs = 1 ).predict( X_observed )`** solo-job was well served on `.predict()`

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to use the most recent version (0.19) of scikit-learn. In the change log, they mentioned in the [bug fixes section](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-19) (indeed, there is a major improvement):

```
 Fixed excessive memory usage in prediction for random forests estimators. #8672 by Mike Benfield.
```

You can install this version by using:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn==0.19.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please train Random Forest with a single tree and check the tree depth. By default, the full tree is grown in scikit-learn. The depth can be very large so even few trees in the Forest can use a lot of memory. You can try to limit the depth of the tree with `max_depth` hyper-parameter.

I run the [experiment](https://mljar.com/blog/random-forest-memory/) when I reduced the depth of trees from 42 (the average depth of tree in the forest) to 6. The memory decreases 66 times while the performance was slightly better (about 4%).